# Is there a way to add horizontal scroll bar for a bar chart made using dimplejs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, dimple.js

I made a bar chart using dimple.js [template](http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=bars_vertical). Here is the code:

```
<div id="chartContainer">
<script src="/lib/d3.v3.4.8.js"></script>
<script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 1000, 1000);
d3.csv("Device_6_energy.csv", function (data) {
  var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
  myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 6000, 305)
  var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Date");
  x.addOrderRule("Time");
  myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Consumption");
  //myChart.width = 6000;
  myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
  myChart.draw();
});
```

Number of values on x-axis is huge. So, I am facing a problem where only some bars of the graph are displayed. The rest just cuts off.

The following is the format of the Time from my .csv file.

```
4/3/2015 20:00
4/3/2015 21:00
4/4/2015 1:00
4/4/2015 3:00
4/4/2015 4:00
4/4/2015 5:00
```

I want to know if there is a way to add a scroll bar at the bottom of the graph to view all the bars till the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks there's no inbuilt support for scrollbar. 
Instead you can use browsers native scrollbar by ***adding*** the `overflow` property .

```
#chartContainer { overflow-x : scroll ;}
```

Comment: Thanks that works when I use it like this:
        svg { overflow-x: scroll;
width: "whatever the total width of the graph is";}

Comment: Sorry about that. New to the website.